# Java constructor keywordS meaning

Tags: java, object, types, constructor

I'm an IT student and I've been trying to program since ever... tho there are still **many** things and concepts I really can't understand after all this time.
One of the most basic one is Java (since I should study that mostly) constructors.

Like ok, I get that a class is a blueprint and we use constructors to make an object and assign values to the class variables, but what how the hell does it work?

```
ExampleClass exampleClassObject = new ExampleClass()
```

Ok so, of course I tried already to look for an answer for this but I guess it's too stupid to even explain it...

There are 4 keywords, right?

**ExampleClass** - is the class we want to make an object of

**exampleClassObject** - is the object name

**= new** - I actually don't know exactly what it does

**ExampleClass()** - THIS. This freaking thing.. what does it do? What's his purpose? Aren't we already telling Java to make an object of ExampleClass with the first keyword?

I think it's the type of our exampleClassObject, but... why do you need to specify that? And if you can change the type of object (as I've seen in other code) whats the point of it??
Making an object of ClassX but of type ClassY... I really don't understand, sorry, and that's just the tip of the iceberg :')

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT 1**
Thanks for the immediate replies! But..

@Michael

> `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); list = new LinkedList<>();`

What's the point of this.. why not making a LinkedList right away? And why making a new object from an already existing object?

I feel like the dude from "1kg of steel vs 1kg of feathers"... I don't get it, thanks so much for the effort lol

**EDIT 2**
To those downvoting, it's not that I didn't look enough online or at the documentation, it's that I don't understand it :) StackOverflow was my last resource, I wouldn't have asked otherwise...

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: `new ExampleClass()` actually that is one thing. It is calling the constructor of `ExampleClass` class. You could call there some other method or just assign another object to that variable, that's why the `ExampleClass` repeatition.

Comment: There is *one* keyword: `new`. Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: This ArrayList/LinkedList thing is just an example, nothing you would expect exactly this way in actual code. It is there to show that the type of the variable is not necessarily the type of the created object - it could be a supertype (and often enough is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are 4 keywords, right?

This is not accurate. A keyword is [a specific thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords). In your case, only `new` is a keyword.

You mean that there are 4 tokens; 4 distinct items for a parser to interpret.

> ExampleClass() - THIS. This freaking thing.. what does it do? What's
>   his purpose? Aren't we already telling Java to make an object of
>   ExampleClass with the first keyword?

You are right, to some degree. There is a kind of declaration redundancy in this particular case. This is one of the reasons people sometimes say that Java is verbose.

In C++ you can do something like this, which contains less repetition

```
ExampleClass exampleClassObject;
ExampleClass exampleClassObject(12);
```

In Java the equivalent would be

```
ExampleClass exampleClassObject = new ExampleClass();
ExampleClass exampleClassObject = new ExampleClass(12);
```

The reason why this is not completely redundant in Java is because you are specifying the type of the variable separately from the type of the instance which the variable initially holds.

For example

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(getSomeItems());
// some operations for a which an array-based list is most efficient
// ...

list = new LinkedList<>();
list.addAll(getSomeDifferentItems());
// some operations for a which a linked list is most efficient
// ...
```

In this case, the type of the variable is more permissive than the type of the instance which it initially holds. This allows us to depend more upon the abstraction than on one specific implementation, and to potentially re-assign a different implementation later.

In [more recent versions of Java](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286), we can use `var` (a reserved type name) to reduce the duplication. In this case, the type of the variable is inferred from the type it is initialized with, so we don't have to write it twice.

```
var myclass = new ExampleClass();
```

Comment: @Rannel Sorry, I didn't think you would take that example literally. Of course you are right that in that example where the reassignment happens immediately after declaration, you may as well have just initialized with the linked list. I have changed the example to be more "realistic" (it is still quite contrived, but still)

Comment: Thanks for that last example regarding implicit type. It seems a lot of newer languages go the way of inferring the type of the lhs, instead of the rhs. But in fact, Java somewhat has both with the addition of the diamond operator for generic types.

Comment: @kutschkem Pretty much every language decision in Java since its inception has been heavily shaped by the desire to maintain backwards compatibility. `var` was able to be introduced in such a way that only broke code for people who had already defined their own classes called `var` -- first of all, not PascalCase. second of all, completely undescriptive. if you did this, you deserve the bad things which happen to you. It's impressive what they've been able to accomplish while (mostly) preserving BC but it's no surprise they can't/don't do the same things as newer langs without that constraint

Comment: @Michael I think this came across the wrong way. I meant to say other languages ALSO, like the most recent Java versions (or should i say this the other way around) do something like the `var` keyword and infer the lhs types.

Comment: You're obviously not the problem here Michael, don't worry :')
I guess it's slightly more clear now.. thanks again. 
So by doing

`existingObject = new DifferentClass()`

we're just casting the object from one class to another? So we can use different methods to manage data inside that object?

Comment: @Rannel No, there is no casting here. We are taking a variable -- that is, a holder for a reference to a class instance which is constrained to a particular type (which could be anything from very broad to very specific) -- throwing away the old value, and replacing it with a reference to a new class instance. The class of the new instance may or may not match the class of the old instance; the only thing that matters is that the type is within the bounds of the constraint imposed by the variable.